# split up the processing time by components

Tags: 2007, administration

is there a way to split the processing time by individual components? means that

1. How much time client browser takes to establish the connection with the server.
2. How much time IIS takes to communicate to SQL?
3. How much time SQL takes to return the results.
4. How much time IIS takes to respond back to the client

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a tool that tracks all those stats at once. You could probably acomplish it using wire shark on each of the respective machines. I guess I would ask why do you want to know, probably you have a slow site? Some things you can do to help that are

1. Turn on Caching http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770229.aspx
2. Use y-Slow in firefox to see what the size of your page is and why it is rendering slow. This will give you the time it takes the browser to load and how long it takes to get the info from the WFE http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/
3. verify that you have your SQL Server setup according to best practices http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263261(office.12).aspx. this best practice doc says it is for 2007 but al most all still applys to 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. You should have a look at SQL Profiler, which provides all the statistics you need, with the exception of browser related ones. Have a look at [this Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&xhr=t&q=sql%20profiler&cp=0&pf=p&sclient=psy&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=sql%20pr&pbx=1&fp=a3d4f2e3af8774d&ion=1&biw=1366&bih=667) for details.

Another option is to track your [SQL Server Performance Counters](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&xhr=t&q=sql%20server%20performance%20counters&cp=24&pf=p&sclient=psy&nord=1&biw=1366&bih=667&site=webhp&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=sql%20server%20performance%20c&pbx=1&fp=a3d4f2e3af8774d&ion=1).

[Idera recently posted](http://www.idera.com/Downloads/ProdCollateral/Tune-Your-DB-Conf-Best-SP-Perf.pdf) some info about tuning your database for SQL Usage as well.

Comment: We had a debate about linking to Google Search results in SO long back :-)

Comment: I don't think I was part of that discussion so please point me to any sources maintained by stack exchange / moderators of this particular site.